# Nav menu wont show on mobile devices

Tags: php, html, css

Having an issue with navigation drop down menu not appearing on website with mobile devices. Using Kingdom Theme

Website: www.fleeknsleek.com

`CSS Snippet:

```css
.navigationbar {
 border: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 }
.kd-menu-effect {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
 display: none;
}
#alternate_menu {
 z-index: 999;
}

html body .kd_alternate_menu .kd_alternate_menu-submenu-items a  {
 color:#333;
}
.navigationbar .container {
 position: relative;
 }
.navigationbar ul.kd_main_menu {
 display: table;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 }
 .navigationbar .kd_main_menu li {
  color: #2f2f2f;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 7px 0 7px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .navigationbar .kd_main_menu li:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
 }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu > li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
   .navigationbar .kd_main_menu > li.homeicon a {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 25px;
   }
    .navigationbar .kd_main_menu > li.homeicon a i {
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu li a {
   color: #2c3e50;
   font-weight: 700;
   letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu li a i.fa {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 5px;
   margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .kd_active,
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu li a:hover {
   color: #781b80;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu > li.current-menu-item a {
   color: #781b80;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .tree-col {
   width: 540px !important;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .two-col {
   width: 320px !important;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .one-col {
   width: 180px !important;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .sub-menu {
   background-color: #ffffff !important;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
   display: none;
   left: 0;
   min-width: 250px;
   overflow: visible !important;
   padding: 15px 25px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 60px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 500;
  }
   .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .sub-menu li {
    background-image: none;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0;
   }
    .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .sub-menu li a {
     color: #262626;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: 700;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     padding: 6px 0;
     text-transform: none;
    }
    .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .sub-menu li:first-child a {
     font-weight: 700;
    }
    .navigationbar .kd_main_menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
     color: #c73030;
    }
    
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
   display: block;
  }
  .navigationbar .kd_main_menu > li:hover i.icon_arrow-menu {
   display: block;
  }
  
  .navigationbar i.icon_arrow-menu {
   left: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 22px;
   display: none;
  }

  .menu-headline {
      display: none;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 99;
      color: #fff;
      margin-top: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
  }
   .menu-headline i {
       position: absolute;
       top: 4px;
       right: 10px;
       font-size: 20px;
   }
```

Php Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
 
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
 
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="kd-menu-effect"></div>
 <?php if( get_theme_mod('enable_top_bar') == 'YES' ) { ?>
  <div class="kd_header_top">
   <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <?php
      if(has_nav_menu( 'top_nav' )){
      ?>
       <!-- Main Menu -->
       <nav class="kd_header_top_menu">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
         'theme_location' => 'top_nav',
         'menu_id' => 'top_nav'
        ));
        ?>
       </nav>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'email' ) ){ ?>
       <div class="kd_email_support">
        <a href="mailto:<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'email' ); ?>"><?php echo get_theme_mod( 'email' ); ?></a>
       </div>
      <?php } ?>
      
      <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'phone_no' ) ){ ?>
       <div class="kd_phone_support">
        <a href="tel:<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'phone_no' ); ?>"><?php echo get_theme_mod( 'phone_no' ); ?></a> 
       </div>
      <?php } ?>
      
      <ul class="kd_header_social_list">
       <?php if( get_theme_mod('head_facebook_url_on') == 'YES' ) { ?>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod('head_facebook_url') ); ?>" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
       <?php if( get_theme_mod('head_twitter_url_on') == 'YES' ) { ?>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod('head_twitter_url') ); ?>" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
       <?php if( get_theme_mod('head_youtube_url_on') == 'YES' ) { ?>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod('head_youtube_url') ); ?>" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
       <?php if( get_theme_mod('head_gplus_url_on') == 'YES' ) { ?>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod('head_gplus_url') ); ?>" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
       <?php if( get_theme_mod('head_instagram_url_on') == 'YES' ) { ?>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod('head_instagram_url') ); ?>" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
       
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php if( has_nav_menu( 'main_nav' ) || has_nav_menu('alternate_nav') ) { ?>
  <!-- Main Menu -->
  <nav class="navigationbar <?php echo has_nav_menu( 'alternate_nav' ) ? 'kd_has_alternate_nav' : ''; ?>">
   <div class="container">

    <?php
    if( has_nav_menu('alternate_nav') ) {
     $menu_name = 'alternate_nav';
     $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
     $menu_id = $locations[ $menu_name ] ;
     $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_id);
     
     echo '<div id="alternate_menu"><span>' . ( $menu->name ) . '</span>';
     wp_nav_menu(array(
      'theme_location' => 'alternate_nav',
      'menu_class' => 'kd_alternate_menu ' . ( get_theme_mod('enable_display') == 'YES' ? "kd_default_open_hp" : '') . '',
      'walker' => new kingdom_themeWalkerMainNav() 
     ));
     echo '</div>';
    }
    if( has_nav_menu( 'main_nav' ) ) {
    ?>
    <div class="menu-headline">
     <span data-alttext="Close Shopping">Shopping</span>
     <i class="micon icon-menu7"></i>
    </div>
    <?php
     wp_nav_menu(array(
      'theme_location' => 'main_nav',
      'menu_class' => 'kd_main_menu',
      'walker' => new kingdom_themeWalkerMainNav() 
     ));
    }
    ?>
   </div>
  </nav>
<?php } ?>
 <!-- Header Elements -->
 <div class="kd_header_bg_color">
 <div class="container ">
  <div class="kd_header_elements">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <?php
      $logo_width = ( get_theme_mod( 'logo_width' ) ) ? get_theme_mod( 'logo_width' ) : '100%';
      $logo_height = ( get_theme_mod( 'logo_height' ) ) ? get_theme_mod( 'logo_height' ) : '100%';
     ?>
     <div class="kd_logo" style="max-width: <?php echo $logo_width; ?>; max-height: <?php echo $logo_height; ?>;">
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
       <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'logo' ) ){
        echo '<img style="max-width: ' . $logo_width . '; max-height:  ' . $logo_height . ';" src="' .  get_theme_mod( 'logo' ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '">';
       } else {
        echo '<img style="max-width: ' . $logo_width . '; max-height:  ' . $logo_height . ';" src="' . esc_url( (kingdom()->cfg['paths']['theme_dir_url']) . '/images/kd_logo.png' ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '">';
       }
       ?>
      </a>
     </div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="kd_search">
      <form role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>" method="get">
       <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
       <button type="submit" class="kd_search_submit" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Search', 'kingdom');?>" ><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
       <input type="text" id="search" name="s" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'type to search', 'kingdom'); ?>" />
      </form>
     </div>
     <?php
     if( kingdom()->is_woo_activated() ) {
     ?>
     <div id="kd_checkout_wrap">
      <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>" class="kd_checkout_button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Checkout', 'kingdom'); ?></a>
      <div class="kd_small-cart">
       <div class="kd_cart-title">
         <i class="micon icon-cart5"></i>
         <?php global $woocommerce; ?>
         <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('View your shopping cart', 'kingdom'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Cart', 'kingdom' ); ?>: 
          <span><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span></a> - 
          <span class="kd_cart-itemsnumber">(<?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'kingdom'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> )</span>
       </div>
       
       <div class="cart-details-wrapper">
        <?php
        //wc_get_template( 'cart/mini-cart.php' ); 
        ?>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- END HEADER ELEMENTS -->
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
 
 <?php  
 if( is_search() == false ) {
  if( isset(kingdom()->coreFunctions->data['layout']) && isset(kingdom()->coreFunctions->data['layout']['revolution_slider_select']) ) {
   $revslider_select = kingdom()->coreFunctions->data['layout']['revolution_slider_select'];
   //var_dump($revslider_select);
   //die;
   if( isset($revslider_select) && $revslider_select != '' && $revslider_select != 'no-slider' ) { 
    echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider alias="' . $revslider_select . '"]');
   }
  }
 }
 ?>
 
 <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
 <?php
 if( !is_front_page() ){
 ?>
  <div class="kd_breadcrumbs_bk">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <?php echo kingdom()->coreFunctions->display_breadcrumbs();?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

I need help fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: works for me using iphone 6 in chrome mobile emulator in dev tools.

Comment: your able too see the menu to nav thru the site?

Comment: Yup. I clicked the menu, links showed, clicked the links, clicked the nav again on those pages, clicked more links... all seems ok to me.

Comment: not working on my android hmm